# What is the difference between single double qoute/apostrophe in template-haskell?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, lenses, haskell-optics

When learning about Haskell lenses with the [Optics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optics) package, i encountered the following example:

```hs
data Person = Person 
 { _name :: String
 , _age  :: Int
 } 

makeLenses ''Person
makePrisms 'Person
```

What does a value of type `Name` represent and what is the difference between that single and double single qoute/apostrophe?

Both seem to have the same type:

```hs
makeLenses, makePrisms :: Name -> DecsQ
```

The [template-haskell documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/template_haskell.html#extension-TemplateHaskellQuotes) is incomprehensible to me. It focuses on syntax and lacks examples:

```
* 'f has type Name, and names the function f. Similarly 'C has type Name and names the data constructor C. In general '⟨thing⟩ interprets ⟨thing⟩ in an expression context.

* ''T has type Name, and names the type constructor T. That is, ''⟨thing⟩ interprets ⟨thing⟩ in a type context.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have two forms of quoting to distinguish between the data constructor and the type constructor.

Consider this variant:

```
 data Person = KPerson 
    { _name :: String
    , _age  :: Int
    } 

makeLenses ''Person   -- the type constructor
makePrisms 'KPerson   -- the data constructor
```

Here it is clear that in one case we use a `Name` for the type constructor while in the other case we refer to a `Name` for the data constructor.

In principle, Haskell could have used a single form of quoting, provided that the names of constructors such as `Person` and `KPerson` are always kept distinct. Since this is not the case, we need to disambiguate between naming the type and data constructors.

Note that, in practice, it is customary to use the same name for both constructors, so this disambiguation is often needed in actual code.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand the quotes as creating meta-representations of type and value constructors distinctively. However, i still don't understand why i can pass type and value names interchangeably: `makeLenses ''Person` and `makeLenses 'KPerson` both seem to work.

Comment: @manews That's a good point. Internally, I can see from the source code that `makeLenses` calls `reifyDatatype` whose documentation states "This function will accept any constructor (value or type) for a type declared with newtype or data". So I guess this makes both work. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/th-abstraction-0.4.3.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Datatype.html#v:reifyDatatype It looks like this was done to make _data families_ work -- not the common case.

Answer (score 3):

Type constructors and term constructors can have the same name in Haskell, so you use double and single ticks, respectively, to indicate the difference. Here is that example from Optics with distinct names:

```
data Person = P 
 { _name :: String
 , _age  :: Int
 } 

makeLenses ''Person
makePrisms 'P
```